# ¿Qué significa '¡Plega a Dios que no mintáis!' (El burlador de Sevilla​ de Tirso de Molina)?

Tags: verbos, significado, conjugación, significado-en-contexto

En la jornada primera de [*El burlador de Sevilla*](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_burlador_de_Sevilla/Acto_I)​ de Tisbea dice cuatro veces:

> ¡Plega a Dios que no mintáis!

From the context of the sentence seems to mean *I pray to God that y'all lie not*.
¿Qué significa *[plega](https://dle.rae.es/plegar?m=form)* aquí? In what mode is [plegar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/plega) here? Imperative perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es una antigua conjugación del verbo [placer](https://dle.rae.es/placer). En el DLE ya no está, pero el diccionario del español de Mexico [dice](https://dem.colmex.mx/ver/placer) que la tercera persona del singular del presente de subjuntivo de *placer* puede ser **plazca** o **plega**, en plural, el pretérito perfecto simple puede ser **plació** o **plugo**, y hay otros tiempos que también tienen formas antiguas. Por tanto, la frase significa:

- ¡Plazca a Dios que no mintáis!